# Help with Moment Generating Function and Probability

Tags: probability, moment-generating-functions

In my Mathematical Statistics textbook, I have the following discrete probability mass function and associated MGF:
$$p(x) = \frac13\ \left(\frac23\right)^{x-1},\qquad x = 1,2,3,\ldots$$

Then, using the geometric series, the mgf of X is
$$ M(t) = E(e^{tX}) = \sum_{x=1}^\infty e^{tx} \frac13\ \left(\frac23\right)^{x-1}$$
$$ = \frac13\ e^t \sum_{x=1}^\infty \left(e^t \frac23\right)^{x-1} $$
$$ = \frac13e^t\left(1-e^t \frac23\right)^{-1}$$

However, I'm unsure of how to get from the initial MGF (on the first line) to the final expression. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first line is
$$ M(t) = E(e^{tX}) = \sum_{x=1}^\infty e^{tx} \frac13\ \left(\frac23\right)^{x-1}$$

Write $e^{tx} = e^{t+t(x-1)} = e^t e^{t(x-1)}$. Then $e^t$ and the fraction $\frac{1}{3}$ are  independent of $x$ and can be taken outside of the summation, giving
$$ M(t) = \frac{1}{3}e^t\sum_{x=1}^\infty e^{t(x-1)} \ \left(\frac23\right)^{x-1}$$

Then note that any expression $p^{qr}$ can be rewritten $(p^{q})^r$, hence $e^{t(x-1)}$ can be rewritten $(e^t)^{x-1}$. Then both $e^t$ and $\frac{2}{3}$ are raised to the power of $x-1$, giving your second line

$$ M(t) = \frac13\ e^t \sum_{x=1}^\infty \left(e^t \frac23\right)^{x-1} $$

Then change variables $y=x-1$

$$ M(t) = \frac13\ e^t \sum_{y=0}^\infty \left(e^t \frac23\right)^y $$

Finally apply the [infinite geometric series formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula)
$$\sum_{y=0}^\infty r^y = \frac{1}{1-r} = (1-r)^{-1}$$

giving your last line

$$ M(t) = \frac13e^t\left(1-e^t \frac23\right)^{-1}$$

Comment: Wow thanks a lot! This will be good practice for me.